# Develop 360 3D video player for Android for VR

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality

I need to integrate in my android app a player for a `VR` video (360 and stereographic). After looking around the web the best I found was `VrVideoView` class from `VR` android SDK, but it is not working properly, as it is still experimental. I also tried with `Unity3D` following [this](http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/) tutorial  but the resolution shown is half of the original (4K).

Any ideas of how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Easy Movie Texture plugin in Unity to have 360 video player. please check this out here https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google VR Sdk for Android, here is a complete documentation and setup guide. https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started